# will ionic plugin 2.2.3 run on ionic 1.3.0?

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm newbie in ionic and I need to create plugins that run on ionic 1.3.0, is that possible if I create the plugin using the ionic 2.2.3 ? will the plugin works or should I develop the plugin using ionic 1.3.0 also?

Comment: are you talking about framework version or cli version?

Comment: @suraj sorry, my bad, I got mixed up between the framework version and cli version, I thought that the framework version = cli version, in fact I just found out that using cli version I can specify which framework I want to install my ionic project by specifying --v1 for ionic framework 1 and --v2 for ionic framework 2..